# Get ifstat value in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to get the values from ifstat shell command in a Python script.
I have try this but not getting it working.

```
import subprocess    
cmd = "ifstat -i wlan0 -b -n | awk 'NR>2 {printf "Download" $1 "Upload" $2}'"
Net = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
print Net
```

## Updated post

When I run ifstat - wlan0 in shell i got this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ifstat -i wlan0
      wlan0
 KB/s in  KB/s out
    7.10      2.56
```

And I want to get the data 7.10 and 2.56 out

Comment: What result are you getting, and what result were you expecting?

Comment: Also, there is a syntax error in `cmd = "ifstat -i wlan0 -b -n | awk 'NR>2 {printf "Download" $1 "Upload" $2}'"`: you need to escape the `"` characters inside the string (i.e. replace `"` with `\"` around `Download` and `Upload`)

Comment: I try this now, and nothing happens? I get no data out.
cmd = "ifstat -i wlan0 -b -n | awk 'NR>2 {printf \"Download\" $1 \"Upload\" $2}'"

Comment: What happens when you run `ifstat -i wlan0 -b -n | awk 'NR>2 {printf "Download" $1 "Upload" $2}'` directly in the shell? Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878967/ifstat-logging-bandwidth-usage) might be helpful

Comment: same thing, nothing at all

Comment: Then your python code is working! Now you need to figure out your shell command.

Comment: updated the post

Comment: got it working now:
cmd = "ifstat -i wlan0 1 1 | awk 'NR>2 {printf \"Download \" $1 \" Upload \" $2}'"